# Winboard: how can I search for a player name in loaded pgn files

Tags: pgn, winboard

I have loaded into `Winboard 32 GUI` this 8GB file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F8QWIkjhrOJdqkNrlN19nnWQpeww-2mv

How can I do advanced search for players names, place ELO etc. ?[image]